# What round brackets means when create object java android programming

Tags: java, android

i new to learn java programming for android. in that tutorial i found the code like this:

```
TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
```

As long as i know in java programming we create object like this:

```
Puppy myPuppy = new Puppy();
```

so what code (TextView) in the first code means? why TextView use round brackets ()

Comment: [JLS-15.16. Cast Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

Comment: it is used to force conversion to a explicit type of object.

Comment: `findViewById` does not create object. `(TextView)` is casting object to the `TextView` type

Comment: ok. thanks for answer and reference to the oracle documentation.